# Can the iOS App communicate with the devices of Bluetooth V2.0 through CoreBluetooth.framework?

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth

I'm developing an App, which is required to communicate with the devices of Bluetooth V2.0, V3.0, or V4.0. The communication is completed through the serial service of Bluetooth. The App is for iPad. We develop it with the Xcode V7.3.1 on the MacBook OS X El Capitan V10.11.4.  There are many materials about the Bluetooth development for iOS, but lots of them are for CoreBluetooth.framework. I indeed tried to connect a device in hands through CoreBluetooth.framework, but it does not work. I have some basic questions about the CoreBluetooth and the Bluetooth-communication development.

1. Suppose the iPad, on which our App runs, has the chip of Bluetooth V4.0 (Smart Ready), can the App establish the Bluetooth connection with the devices of Bluetooth V2.0 or V3.0 through CoreBluetooth.framework? and then communicate with them?
2. If the answer of the 1st question is "No!", are there any other APIs available for the iOS App to communicate with the Bluetooth devices? If there are, what are they? Of course, we suppose that the Bluetooth devices are the MFi Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices which support Bluetooth Low Energy (v4.0) can connect and accept connections from other BLE compatible devices.

However, in order to connect using older protocols, you would need to become a member of the MFI program.

Hope this helps

Comment: We develop the App software, which runs on the iPad, and needs to read the messages sent from a Bluetooth device. However, not only we do not produce any hardware devices, but also do not produce the firmware for any devices. Do we need to enroll in the MFi program?

Only the producers of the Bluetooth devices need to enroll the MFi. Is it right?

Really appreciate your information!